# Sending/retrieving score pairs to/from Game Center

Tags: ios4, game-center

I am making an iPhone game that will be using Game Center to support leaderboards, achievements etc. My game qualifies the player's performance using two quantities: speed and accuracy. However I would like to report these two scores at the same time, for example:

speed: 20m/s and accuracy: 75%,

and later be able to retrieve that specific combination of speed and accuracy as a single score.

As I have noticed, Game Center reports only the highest scores per category per player. Using a combined leaderboard does not seem to be the answer as this provides just a pair of the highest scores per category for a specific player.

I have also come up with providing a combined score format in points to account for speed and accuracy:

2075 points

which would translate to 20 m/s and 75% accuracy. This would require making another leaderboard that will display aggregate scores in points - which is a bit quirky at least for this type of game, unless this leaderboard could be hidden from the player, not very likely in Game Center.

Could anyone think of a better option? Perhaps openfeint offers more options for score reporting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went for the solution of combining scores in one aggregate score. It is quite handy for submitting and receiving 2 scores in one go. To support individual high scores for speed and accuracy on Game Center I will be submitting the aforementioned scores individually as well.